# Using date functions in where clause of SQL

Tags: sql, presto

My question is regarding particular use case of SQL.

I am trying out [querybook](https://www.querybook.org/) and [presto type sql](https://prestodb.io/) for a work project.

I deciphered that while writing SQL queries in [querybook](https://www.querybook.org/) - it follows a different style of SQL which is Presto.

I want to write a SQL query which can:

- give all entries from a table where the created_at_unix_timestamp > unix_timestamp_of_past_hour

There are some functions like FROM_UNIXTIME and TO_UNIXTIME which I'm experimenting with - but all of these functions are usable in the 1st part of the query

```
select *
```

where we describe the fields we want from a table

Is it possible to write a query like this

```
select *
from table
where to_unixtime(field_in_table) > some_unix_timestamp_value_calculated_at_runtime
```

I am not able to find any documentation around this.

An update:
when i try this - it's giving an error
[image]

Final Update:
It's working with this syntax:

select * from events.table where event_name='some_event_name' and consumer_timestamp > ( CAST(to_unixtime(CAST(LOCALTIMESTAMP AS timestamp)) AS BIGINT) - 3590) order by consumer_timestamp DESC limit 10

Comment: i had done it by mistake, corrected it

Comment: There is a function that gives the current timestamp inside presto. https://duckduckgo.com/?q=presto+current+timestamp&t=brave&ia=web
Once you have just subtract the 3600 to entries in the last hour.
If you want entries since the start of the last you could create a new timestamp from the current timestamp and set the minutes, seconds to zero.

Comment: The function is 'current_timestamp'.

Comment: @KeithJohnHutchison
im trying out a few queries like this:
select event_timestamp_raw from events.table where FROM_UNIXTIME(consumer_timestamp) <  CURRENT_TIME order by consumer_timestamp DESC limit 1

select event_timestamp_raw from events.table where consumer_timestamp < TO_UNIXTIME(CURRENT_TIME) order by consumer_timestamp DESC limit 1

but not working

Comment: I don't use presto, however I've worked with mysql, postgresql and mssql,  FROM_UNIXTIMESTAMP would to me be converting a unix_timestamp - a bit int - to a timestamp  ... current_time gives the time ... should be current_timestamp - you'll also what to use whatever delta function there is to find current_timestamp - 3600 seconds.

Comment: @Probosckie Is your query still failing?

Comment: @PrabhakarReddy
no with a little bit of trial and error I made it work like this: select * from events.table where consumer_timestamp > ( CAST(to_unixtime(CAST(LOCALTIMESTAMP AS timestamp)) AS BIGINT) - 3590) order by consumer_timestamp DESC limit 10

Comment: You could write that up as an answer.